# importing QtCore/QtGui vs plain Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there any advantage or disadvantage of `import`ing `PyQt4.QtGui` and `PyQt4.QtCore` over `PyQt.Qt`?

I have seen many examples using either and both seem to serve the same purpose, so is there a reason to choose importing those two classes over the seemingly all-in-one Qt class?

Comment: That's like asking: is there any disadvantage to importing *all* the modules in site-packages, rather than just the one or two I actually need?

Comment: For someone who doesn't understand how the python bindings for Qt work, this is an interesting question. If you know the disadvantages, why not provide an answer, @ekhumoro? :)

Comment: @Mitch. Well, my point was that It's got nothing to do with pyqt *per se* - it's just a case of importing more versus less.

Comment: No, there is no advantage or disadvantage really. They both achieve more or less the same. Use whatever you like more.